# How to get original url path in webflux ServerHttpRequest

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

**How to get absolute URL as written in RequestMapping ?**

The code given below :

`@RequestMapping("/user/{id}")
 public User get(){
   String url  = "/user/{id}";
 };`

Comment: I want url from ServerHttpRequest like specified above

Comment: I want requestmapping value

Answer (score 1):

`ServerHttpRequest request = (ServerHttpRequest) exchange.getRequest();`

Using  `request.getURI().getPath()` I am able to get the API path.

```
 @Component
    public class ServerAuthEntryPointJwt implements ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint {
    
        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServerAuthEntryPointJwt.class);
    
        @Override
        public Mono<Void> commence(ServerWebExchange exchange, AuthenticationException ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            logger.error("Unauthorized error: {}", ex.getMessage());
    
            ServerHttpRequest request = (ServerHttpRequest) exchange.getRequest(); 
            ServerHttpResponse response = (ServerHttpResponse) exchange.getResponse();
    
    //    response.set(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
            response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    
            final Map<String, Object> body = new HashMap<>();
            body.put("status", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            body.put("error", "Unauthorized");
            body.put("message", ex.getMessage());
            body.put("path", request.getURI().getPath());
            response.getHeaders().add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
            JSONObject fadfa = new JSONObject(body);
            byte[] bytes = fadfa.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            DataBuffer buffer = exchange.getResponse().bufferFactory().wrap(bytes);
            return exchange.getResponse().writeWith(Flux.just(buffer));
    
        }
    
    }
```

**Response :**

```
{
        "path": "/admin-service/conversation-management/conversations",
        "error": "Unauthorized",
        "message": "Not Authenticated",
        "status": "UNAUTHORIZED"
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

U can add a filter and check get the value from request.getPath().contextPath().value()

```
@Component
public class Interceptor  implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
       ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
       String path = request.getPath().contextPath().value()
    }
}
```

references
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.RC3_to_5.0.0.RC4/Spring%20Framework%205.0.0.RC4/org/springframework/http/server/reactive/ServerHttpRequest.html
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.RC3_to_5.0.0.RC4/Spring%20Framework%205.0.0.RC4/org/springframework/http/server/RequestPath.html
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.RC3_to_5.0.0.RC4/Spring%20Framework%205.0.0.RC4/org/springframework/http/server/PathContainer.html